# How to filter not in records from a dataframe using values from a another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes  `Source` and `Target` .I want to select the rows from source datafame which dont have matching version value in target. Datatypes of version in both dataframes are object.

How can this be done?

```
Source

kg   from  to  version
0.5  AU    DE  2019-12-02 13:49:31
0.5  AU    DE  2018-12-02 18:45:11
0.5  AU    DE  2020-07-08 03:15:21
0.5  DE    US  2020-07-08 03:09:21
0.5  DE    US  2019-12-02 13:49:31
0.5  DE    US  2020-06-07 03:09:21
1    AE    INR 2017-08-09 13:19:28
1    AE    INR 2020-06-07 03:09:21

Target

 Target['version']
 2017-08-09 13:19:28
 2018-12-02 18:45:11
 2019-12-02 13:49:31
```

**Expected Output**

```
kg   from  to  version
0.5  AU    DE  2020-07-08 03:15:21
0.5  DE    US  2020-06-07 03:09:21
0.5  DE    US  2020-07-08 03:09:21
1    AE    INR 2020-06-07 03:09:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Source[~Source['version'].isin(Target['version'])]
```

This will exclude any rows of `Source` where `version` exists in `Target`.